# Error while loading assembly on separated AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, appdomain

My application creates multiple AppDomains and I manually configure the binding redirects via the SetConfigurationBytes method. I grab the config file, check for all assemblies installed on the private folder and then set the assemblyRedirect as on the example below. This is to ensure that I'll always use the shipped version of a given assembly:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="2.2.18.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

However, when an assembly being loaded in a different AppDomain depends upon the System.Net.Http assembly, I get the following error: System.IO.FileLoadException: **Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances.**

There's two possible ways I've saw to solving this: either by removing the `<dependentAssembly>` element on the config for this DLL, or to add this assembly on the GAC.

I didn't like any of this because the first may cause problems with other assemblies and the second relies on the GAC, which some of my clients don't like.

Anyone have a different idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that some assemblies (most notably, interop assemblies) are *not* domain-specific. They use a shared domain, and thus they can only be loaded once in a process. You need to make sure that *all* the domains use the exact same assembly when that's the case. Or use full trust, but that comes with its own can of worms, of course :)

Comment: Thanks, Luaan. I would not like to use full trust, do you have some example on how to ensure the loading of the same assembly ? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like my issue is with the setup of the AppDomain -- I noticed that the AppDomains were being created with LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost, and this will only share GAC assemblies. The assembly that is buging me is _not_ on the GAC, so my best approach is to use the LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain. It worked for me this way.